# JCrop: Adding text to selection area - possible?

Tags: javascript, selection, jcrop

I'm intending to use JCrop for a standard image upload feature. 
Everything is all right so far, it works great.
BUT: there is a minimum image size required, so instead of letting the user do his cropping and then stop him with an error message when he tries to ulpoad, I'd like to insert a continuous (or at least after selecting) info-text about the current selection size.
So, here's my question: can you add text to the jcrop selection area? Or would I have to create something myself?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no you can't add text to the selection area.  You could, of course make additions to the jcrop script and add such functionality (which I think would be a cool addition).

I had a similar need (ie. to inform user that it was too small) and did it in a separate area based on the selection size.  Something along the lines of:

```
$("#myDiv").Jcrop({onChange: checkSelection},function(){jcrop_api = this;));

function checkSelection(c){
  if (c.x2 - c.x < minWidth)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought along those lines, too. Well, got to pimp JCrop then ;)